# Quando chegar a 12:00 todos os dias escrever no console

Tags: c#

Como faço para que quando o tempo no meu computador chegar a 12:00 ele escrevesse no console "Hello World" todos os dias?

Comment: Não consigo perceber o que quer perguntar.

Comment: Pronto editei..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria um **Timer** e em seguida compara com o horário escolhido:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Pressione \'q\' para sair.");
    while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
}

private static void TimerCallback(object stateInfo)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 00 && DateTime.Now.Second == 00)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Queria que fosse todos os dias

Comment: se você deixar a aplicação em execução irá rodar todos os dias ao 12:00...